# Postgresql object ID and tuples

Tags: postgresql

I sometimes see messages like

Process 12990 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (889,66) of relation 17720 of database 17607; blocked by process 12992.

So of course the 'process' part is quite clear, but I don't know how to correlate between the relation ID and a human readable name.  I also don't really know what to make of the tuple bit.

Anyone know how to read these messages and how to glean useful data from them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can look this up the system tables : the one of interest here is [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-class.html).

Doing a query like

```
SELECT OID, relname FROM pg_class
 oid  |              relname               
-------+------------------------------------
  1247 | pg_type
 11550 | user_mapping_options
 11554 | user_mappings
 11494 | triggered_update_columns
 11497 | triggers
```

or rather

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE OID=17720
```

might shed light on the locks.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured out the id to relation mapping, but still not sure what to make of the tuples...

Comment: Actually, I should clarify - not sure how to read the tuple notation (x,y) and how I can use that to understand what caused the deadlock

Comment: OK, another bit of data found - the numbers are transaction IDs that inserted or deleted that tuple/row.

Is there any way I can get an idea of which SQL those transactions were running?

Answer (score 50):

A "relation" is a table and a "tuple" is a row.

Here's [a nice shortcut](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2011/10/deadlocks.html) for getting the name of the table from the table id (you can also query the `pg_class` table):

```
=> select 17720::regclass;
┌──────────┐
│ regclass │
├──────────┤
│ my_table │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

Now how about the row? The "tuple bit" is a [tuple identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-oid.html), and every table in your database has a special [system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html) called `ctid` where those identifiers are stored. Now that we know the table in question, we can do:

```
=> select * from my_table where ctid='(889,66)';
```

However! From the system column docs (emphasis added): "[A]lthough the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, **a row's ctid will change** if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier." In other words, if you're quick enough you can probably trust that the row returned is the one involved in the deadlock, but that info won't be available forever.