# PostgreSQL: determine a database name from a database ID?

Tags: postgresql

In a deadlock situation, I see these messages from PostgreSQL.

```
Process 60630 waits for ShareRowExclusiveLock on relation 1220970 of database 1220621; blocked by process 60626.
Process 60626 waits for ShareUpdateExclusiveLock on relation 1223887 of database 1220621; blocked by process 60630.
```

I know that I can get the table names using `SELECT 1220970::regclass`.

But how do I determine a database name from the database ID?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570387/postgresql-object-id-and-tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the system catalog:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE oid = 1220621;
```